# Missing page on wordpress "Pages" dashboard

Tags: pages, dashboard

I just put up a new site (http://universalpluminfo.azurewebsites.net/) and was starting to add the base pages.

I think something may have went wrong as I have 5 pages on the navigation bar, but only 4 pages on the Pages Dashboard. I am missing the "Home" page that I created from the dashboard.

Any ideas on what could cause this or how to remedy?

[image: Missing pages]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "catch-base" theme was the culprit.

`Appearance > Customize > Static Front Page` then had to set the options for the Front page and the extra "Home" button went away.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have added just navigation item in menu, named `Home`. Go to `Appearence> menus` and modify the menu in question. There should be the extra item, named `Home`, which is not created as page.

Comment: There is no menu setup in there. The navigation is set to solely use the pages as navigation items.